# Subquery vs Join and where - which one is faster?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have two sql's which gives me same results:

Query 1:

```
SELECT
u.*, COUNT(po.order_id) products_count
FROM (SELECT * FROM orders o WHERE o.date >= (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) o
LEFT JOIN products_orders po ON po.order_id=o.id
JOIN users u ON u.id=o.user_id
GROUP BY po.order_id
```

and Query 2:

```
SELECT
u.*, o.id order_id, COUNT(po.order_id) products_count
FROM users u
JOIN orders o ON o.user_id=u.id
LEFT JOIN products_orders po ON po.order_id=o.id
WHERE o.date >= (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY po.order_id
```

I wonder.. which one should be faster?
Query Explains shows them to be equals... What do you think guys?
[image: Query 1]
[image: Query 2]

Comment: See also the cross-posting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109913/subquery-vs-join-and-where-which-one-is-faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aggregation doesn't make much sense (and most databases, and even latest versions of MySQL will reject it - See [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by))... you probably want to `GROUP BY o.user_id`, (and maybe, also `orders_id`, but then add it also on the `SELECT` clause) and you can have something a bit quicker if done this way:

```
SELECT
    u.*, c.order_count, c.products_count
FROM
    (SELECT
         o.user_id, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) AS order_count, 
         COUNT(po.order_id)   AS products_count
    FROM
        orders o
        LEFT JOIN products_orders po ON po.order_id = o.id
    WHERE 
        o.date >= (now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)        
    GROUP BY
        o.user_id
    ) AS c
    JOIN users u ON u.id = c.user_id ;
```

The execution plan for this query *is* different, and uses a derived table (which MySQL or MariaDB aren't always very good at), but it will seek your users only once.

You can check out all the details at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=664c71000be1ead931f685b5074ad07a)*

Comment: @breq - If you really wanted one row per order, and the `order_id` included in the output, replace `COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) AS order_count` with `po.order_id`, add `po.order_id` to the `GROUP BY`, and replace `c.order_count` with `c.order_id`. **However**, even if this *is* what you really need, you should see if you maybe don't need *everything* from `users`. A reduced column list there could impact performance, reducing the bandwidth required to transmit the results (if relevant), and possibly changing where the engine looks for the `users` data (could be a  covering index, for instance).

Comment: This avoids the "inflate-deflate" that occurs in `JOIN ... GROUP BY`, which can ruin performance and/or produce the wrong values for aggregates.

Comment: @RickJames: that was the idea...